# Print Strings in Python (TestDome)

Tags: python, collections

I am new to `Python` and have decided to have some exercise in `TestDome`. Below is the Code to an [easy question](https://www.testdome.com/d/python-interview-questions/9) from that website but because it does not print the result as it should, I get zero as a score.

```
class IceCreamMachine:
all={}
def __init__(self, ingredients, toppings):
    self.ingredients = ingredients
    self.toppings = toppings

def scoops(self):
    for i in range(0,len(self.ingredients)):
        for j in range(0,len(self.toppings)):
            print ([self.ingredients[i],self.toppings[j]])

machine = IceCreamMachine(["vanilla", "chocolate"], ["chocolate sauce"])
print(machine.scoops()) #should print[['vanilla', 'chocolate sauce'], ['chocolate', 'chocolate sauce']]
```

Can anybody give a Hint how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to return the value.

Try:

```
class IceCreamMachine:
    all={}
    def __init__(self, ingredients, toppings):
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.toppings = toppings

    def scoops(self):
        res = []
        for i in self.ingredients:
            for j in self.toppings:
                res.append([i, j])
        return res

machine = IceCreamMachine(["vanilla", "chocolate"], ["chocolate sauce"])
print(machine.scoops())
```

Answer (score 4):

I have even a shorter version of code for this problem.I am using list comprehension to solve this:

```html
class IceCreamMachine:
    
    def __init__(self, ingredients, toppings):
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.toppings = toppings
        
    def scoops(self):
        return [[i,j] for i in self.ingredients for j in self.toppings]

machine = IceCreamMachine(["vanilla", "chocolate"], ["chocolate sauce"])
print(machine.scoops()) #should print[['vanilla', 'chocolate sauce'], ['chocolate', 'chocolate sauce']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for range like `for i in range(0,len(self.ingredients)):`you can simply use 
 `for i in elements` and get each element from both the lists and append to new list. (k in this case).

```
class IceCreamMachine:

    def __init__(self, ingredients, toppings):
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.toppings = toppings

    def scoops(self):
        k=[]
        for i in self.ingredients:
            for j in self.toppings:
               k.append([i,j])
        return k

machine = IceCreamMachine(["vanilla", "chocolate"], ["chocolate sauce"])
print(machine.scoops()) #should print[['vanilla', 'chocolate sauce'], ['chocolate', 'chocolate sauce']]
```